# Работа с Redmine .NET API

Tags: redmine

Подскажите пожалуйста как задать задаче (Issue) источник при создании ?

Comment: Что именно вы подразумеваете под источником?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.